# Using phrase 打不死

Tags: word-choice, mandarin, usage

I recently encountered 打不死 as the title of a column in a US Chinese language newspaper. Asking my Chinese language teacher, she gave the literal translation of "beaten but not dead", meaning something like immortal or resilient. She wasn't clear about this being a common phrase (she's from Shanghai if it's relevant) so I would like to know about that and in what context it may be used.

Answer (score 8):

打不死 is of a fine, common idiomatic structure Ｘ不Ｙ, where Ｘ is some verb that cannot be completed, e.g.:

- 吃不完 (implying that there is too much food to be finished)
- 做不動 (implying that you are unable to finish doing a difficult task)
- 找不到 (implying that some object is too hard to find)

*Immortal* or *resilient* are the correct implied meanings of 打不死, but *beaten but not dead* is problematic, as the word *beaten* carries two slightly different nuances:

- *Struck* or *been hit*, which is the literal translation of「打」;
- *Been defeated* (e.g. "I've beaten you at this game")

When I hear the phrase *beaten but not dead*, it sounds like someone's been in a fight and was defeated in the fight, but managed to escape with their life. 打不死 does not carry any notion that one side was defeated in a fight - rather, it carries the notion that one side is extremely resilient to being attacked.

Answer (score 3):

It's often used as an adjectival phrase (打不死的xxx) as in 打不死的小强, meaning *someone who can not be defeated or killed*. 小强 roughly means *newbie*.

When it's used as a verbal phrase, it means: ***one can not be killed by means of beating***. For example, 你打不死他: *you can not beat and kill him*.

Comment: Doesn’t 小强 mean cockroach?

Comment: 小强，https://baike.baidu.com/item/小强/3270?fr=aladdin 多指蟑螂，据说最早把蟑螂叫小强是在广东香港地区，“小强”这个别名源于周星驰的电影《唐伯虎点秋香》。蟑螂有很多名称，其实正式名称为蜚蠊。Even if it started out as a topolectical thing, I’m pretty sure most mainlanders know it now.

Comment: @user3306356, i'm not sure the etymology. 但在玩游戏的时候，小强经常指一些新手或者新人但又实力还可以的选手.

Answer (score 2):

For a real-life context, to quote a line from the lyric of Hong Kong rock band Beyond's 不再犹豫 (Hesitate No More):

> 自信打不死的心态活到老

which roughly translates to *I believe I will live all my life in the spirit of 打不死*.

Answer (score 1):

打不死 literally means "can't be beaten to death"

Simple translation would be  "[invulnerable](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/invulnerable?s=t)" ( *incapable of being wounded, hurt, or damaged*)

'打不死' mainly describe a tough, resilience and often combative character

James bond in 007 movies and John McClane in Die Hard are typical '打不死' hero characters

Unlike 不败 or 無敵 (invincible), a 打不死 doesn't necessary to be an overpowering character